# Add a space after comma in an array

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-markers

I have a PHP code giving back an array

```
<?php
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM Building";
$result5 = $connect->query($sql5);
$emparray = array();
while($row5 = $result5->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $coordLat = floatval($row5['Building_lat']);
    $coordLng = floatval($row5['Building_lng']);
    $emparray[] = array( $row5['Building_name'] , $coordLat , $coordLng , $row5['Building_period'] );
}
$jsonstring= json_encode($emparray);
?>
```

output from $jsonstring is

```
[["Hotel Montgomery",50.85000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,4.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,"June"]]
```

I need to use these array to put markers on a Google Map.
That's where JavaScript enter the game.

```
markers1 = <?php echo $jsonstring; ?>;
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(50.85,4.34);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: center,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        styles: noPoi
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}
function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}
```

Problem is, I need to add a space after the comma of each array in order to make it work. Otherwise, the coordinates doesn't work.

If I write it manually (without the echo, adding space), it's working. Of course these array come from an SQL query and I need an echo to get all datas.

Comment: How is `javascript` tag any related to this? Instead of `php`?

Comment: Hi, we can't help you unless you give us some data to play with and/or some debug info. For example, what does the output of `echo $jsonstring` look like? Or what exactly does "not working" mean? Also: deleted irrelevant stuff from your post.

Comment: hey, I updated my post. do you need more info?

Comment: @LaurentJacobs: arrays are 0-based, so  it should be `...LatLng(marker[1], marker[2])`

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, what you need is join your array, transform into a string with a particular pattern. Try `echo join(", ", $emparray);` if matches your case then just use this return in a variable instead of your `$jsonstring`.